# Number density of stars on the Galactic plane

Tags: milky-way, disk

The number density of stars (e.g. the number of stars per cubic parsec) is given by 
$$N(z) = N(0) e^{-|z|/h}$$
where $z$ is the height above the Galactic plane, $h$ is the scale height for a specific component of the Galaxy, and $N(z)$ is the number density at different heights above the plane.

The scale heights for the thin disk and thick disks are:

- Halo stars: $h=3\textrm{kpc}$
- Thick disk: $h=1.5\textrm{kpc}$
- Thin disk stars: $h=300\textrm{pc}$
- Thin disk gas: $h=100\textrm{pc}$

Unfortunately I cannot find the values for the number density at the galactic plane: $N(0)$

Do you have any references in which I can find these numbers?

Comment: Where did you get this formula, and didn't it provide a value for N(0)? Possibly helpful URLs: http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Bothun2/Bothun4_2_2.html https://www.astro.virginia.edu/class/whittle/astr553/Topic05/Lecture_5.html

Comment: @barrycarter I got it from a course on the Milky Way I did a few years back, it's not available online. Thanks for the link, I should have realised that the values for $N(z)$ depend on the radial distance from the Milky Way's core as your reference mentions.

Comment: I meant $N(0)$ of course.

Comment: The stellar halo is definitely not appropriately described by a vertically exponential, but by a (galactocentric) radial power-law. Also, for most disc populations, $\mathrm{sech}^2(z/h)$ gives a better description than the exponential, but these are details.

Comment: @barrycarter the UVA link is dead; try the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20070322120107/http://www.astro.virginia.edu/class/whittle/astr553/Topic05/Lecture_5.html)

Answer (score 2):

The number density of stars is not well constrained, because it hinges critically on the behaviour of the stellar mass function at low stellar masses. Low-mass stars tend to be dim and hard to detect. What is reasonably well constrained, instead is the mass density of stars, where low-mass objects contribute little, even if their number is large.

Comment: I can't argue with the content of this, but it's not helpful for the question. The value of $N_0$ is of course defined for a particular mass range (as is the scale height).